# Staging Shopsite live on active shop. Database?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, staging

I have created a staging for our onlineshop.
I also upgraded and installed all patches.

Now I would like to put the upgraded site live.
The main question is:
Was the database also changed during the upgrade or can I continue to use the active web database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your database was upgraded on staging.

You will have to perform the upgrade again on live using the same procedure you did on staging.